# How to link to section in same static page?

Tags: theming

How to create a menu link to the section that will display when I click on the link and hide when i again click on the link..

**link is**

```
    <a href="#contact" class="page-scroll"><span>contact me</span></a>
```

**the above link should open**

```
<section id="contact" class="cat-pages">
//some code
</section>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly – are you looking for a way to ***toggle*** (show/hide) an elemet?

Comment: u can say this but not exactly, its like showing a section on click there is 4 sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Jquery and a tiny bit of css.

**Javascript**

```
$('.page-scroll').click(function() {
    $('.cat-pages').toggle('slow');
});
```

**css**

```
.cat-pages { display: none; }
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/2227/)

**edit:**

To use jquery in drupal you use

```
(function ($) {
    // code goes here
})(jQuery);
```

go to drupal/sites/all/themes/YourTheme/

look for your  theme.info file and add this line in there

```
scripts[] = js/myscript.js
```

Then go drupal/sites/all/themes/YourTheme/js and create myscript.js file.

put this inside it

```
(function ($) {
    $('.cat-pages').hide();
    $('.page-scroll').click(function() {
        $('.cat-pages').toggle('slow');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

If the above doesn't work, try

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {  
    $('.cat-pages').hide();
            $('.page-scroll').click(function() {
                $('.cat-pages').toggle('slow');
            });
    }); 
        })(jQuery);
```

**PS:**

Don't worry about `.cat-pages { display: none; }`css anymore, since I added the hide in the jquery `$('.cat-pages').hide();`

Comment: thank you..its working fine in fiddle but how i can use it in drupal 7...

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you its working fine..to achieve my goals i have to play with my css...thank you ..